# c# - UpdatePanel refresh on second button click

Tags: c#, html, updatepanel

I'm trying to change a div content inside an UpdatePanel.

The code I wrote successfully changes the div, but only at the second button click, not on the first.

It's like the UpdatePanel.Update() it's not refreshing the html.

Please note that everything (button and div) is inside a modal.

Here the html portion:

```
   <div class="modal-body">
        <form name="frmInsOpe">
            <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true"></asp:ScriptManager>
            <asp:Button ID="btnInsOpe" Text="Button" OnClick="btnInsOpe_Click" runat="server" />
        </form>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <div id="frameModal" runat="server"></div>
            </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnInsOpe"/>
            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
```

And the .cs

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Reload(string url)
    {
        string responseFromServer = String.Empty;

        try
        {
            string strBuffer = "";
            byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strBuffer);

            //Initialization
            HttpWebRequest WebReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            //Our method is post, otherwise the buffer (postvars) would be useless

            WebReq.Method = "POST";
            //We use form contentType, for the postvars.
            WebReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            //The length of the buffer (postvars) is used as contentlength.
            WebReq.ContentLength = buffer.Length;

            //We open a stream for writing the postvars
            Stream PostData = WebReq.GetRequestStream();
            //Now we write, and afterwards, we close. Closing is always important!
            PostData.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            PostData.Close();

            //Get the response handle, we have no true response yet!
            HttpWebResponse WebResp = (HttpWebResponse)WebReq.GetResponse();

            //Now, we read the response (the string), and output it.
            Stream Answer = WebResp.GetResponseStream();

            // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Answer);

            // Read the content.
            responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();

            // Clean up the streams.
            reader.Close();
            Answer.Close();
            WebResp.Close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            responseFromServer = String.Format("<div><input type='text' value='Errore durante la richiesta: {0}' /></div>", ex.Message);
        }

        // Display the content.
        frameModal.Attributes["innerHtml"] = responseFromServer;
        UpdatePanel1.Update();
    }

    protected void btnInsOpe_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
       Reload(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["myUrl"]);
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is `.Attributes["innerHtml"]` going to set the innerHtml property or just an attribute on the element? Personally I would probably put a Literal element inside the div and set the text of that.

Comment: I need to put html code inside my page, basically the div (or it could even be a frame if needed) is a page from a different website that I need to open inside my webapp

Comment: I'm aware of what you're trying to do, I'm asking if the way you're doing it is actually going to work. The method I suggest would definitely work though..

Comment: Oh sorry!
As I said, in the second button click the page is shown correctly, with the html portion taken during the first button click (followed in debug the "responseFromServer" value and the "frameModal" value)
It just doesn't show it with UpdatePanel1.Update() the first time

Comment: BTW I tried adding a literal inside the div and now it works, thanks!